# sum over arbitrary subsets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. We want to show that $|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n|$ (or $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |a_n|$) is finite. Is it sufficient to show the following?

For any finite $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$, there exists a $B\supset A$ such that $|\sum_{n\in B} a_n|$ (or $\sum_{n\in B} |a_n|$) is less than some absolute constant (i.e. indepdent of $A$ and $B$)?

What if we add an additional condition that $B$ is also finite?

Comment: The meaning of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|a_n|$ is standard, but what precisely is the definition of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} a_n$ (the former, but not the latter, is a sum of nonnegative terms, this is defined for any index set).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that series with positive terms are easier than other ones. In particular, a series $\sum_n a_n$ with $a_n \geq 0$ is convergent or it is divergent to $+ \infty$. Moreover its sum is independent on the order of summation of its terms.

Let $\{ a_n \}_{n \in I}$ be a family of complex numbers indexed by any countable set $I$ (for example $I = \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$).

If you want to show that $\sum_{n \in I} |a_n|$ is convergent, it is sufficient to show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\forall F \subseteq I$ finite set of indeces
$$\sum_{n \in F} |a_n| \leq C$$

This is a very nice property following from the fact that the sum does not depend on the order of summation.

While, if you want to treat the series $\sum_{n \in I} a_n$, you have to define what is the order of its summation, otherwise it is not defined. Only after this choice (which is arbitrary) you can speak about $|\sum_{n \in I} a_n|$.

The two approaches are very different. In the first case you are computing a limit you know exists, and you can use the squeeze theorem to prove that it is finite. In the second case you don't know a priori the limit exist.

Comment: I thought $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n$ could be defined by the limit of $\sum_{n=-k}^{k} a_n$. For sum over $B$, we just consider the terms in the intersection of [-k,k] and B, then take limit.